# How unwise is it to exclude WSL from Windows Defender?

Tags: windows, antivirus

Windows Defender often takes up a significant amount of CPU time due to I/O operations in WSL. For example, if I'm working on web development and using tools like `npm` or `yarn`, downloading packages takes a considerable amount of time as compared to when I disable Windows Defender real-time protection. This is also the case with Android Studio for mobile development.

As an alternative to disabling the anti-virus completely, this article suggests adding WSL to the list of exclusions:

https://medium.com/@leandrw/speeding-up-wsl-i-o-up-than-5x-fast-saving-a-lot-of-battery-life-cpu-usage-c3537dd03c74

Having done that, I noticed an improvement—the same as when I disabled Windows Defender.

However, I'm really concerned about the security implications of doing this. In particular:

- I have public and private `ssh` key pairs in WSL that are used to authenticate my GitHub. If someone were to gain access to these, they could potentially do some nasty stuff.
- WSL itself has access to the Windows file system. I have limited information security knowledge, but I see this as something to be worried about.
- Some researchers have suggested that it's possible to use ["Bashware"](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10s-subsystem-for-linux-heres-how-hackers-could-use-it-to-hide-malware/) in WSL to exploit Windows security vulnerabilities.

So I'm at a crossroads. I either have to suffer an extreme loss of productivity or potentially expose myself to malware. What are my options here?

Comment: Is Windows Defender even equipped to handle non-Windows malware?

Comment: There are comparatively fewer viruses that target Linux than Windows, so I guess _that's_ not too important. The issue is that WSL is installed on Windows itself. And though I don't know the technical details of how it works, my understanding is that infiltrating WSL would allow you to do the same for Windows since WSL has access to the entire Windows file system, and vice versa.

Comment: @AleksandrH did you found more info about this? I have the exact same question.

Comment: @distante Nope. I still disable Windows Defender to this day whenever installing things via WSL, lol...

Comment: @distante Also, I've heard that WSL2 is much, much faster than WSL1 when it comes to yarn and npm (in the order of 20x faster), but it does have memory leak issues that are [currently being addressed](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4166). Not sure which one you're using, but I'm still on WSL1.

Comment: @AleksandrH I am using WSL1 (mostly because windows says my PC is not ready for the May Update... but my 10 years old laptop was...

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what your risk profile is. Is this your personal computer or one you use for work? Are you behind a corporate network/firewall or just on your home network?

What's the worst thing that could happen if you did download a virus on WSL? Remember malware on WSL can still access the rest of your computer. While there isn't as much malware for linux (or WSL) it doesn't mean they don't exist so this is something you would need to take into account. If you are just downloading NPM/YARN packages you might be okay but it is still possible to [inadvertently install malware from NPM packages.](https://www.zdnet.com/article/malicious-npm-packages-caught-installing-remote-access-trojans/)

Some options you could consider to mitigate the risk:

1. You could just do the odd malware scan to make sure you are okay
2. You could set up a linux VM on your machine and do your dev in there. This means any malware you might download during development wouldn't affect the rest of your machine.
3. You could set up some Linux VMs elsewhere to you (e.g. AWS EC2 instance). If you make sure they are immutable (aka you can easily kill one and start a new one and just continue) you wouldn't need any VMs locally, your local machine is safe and you can easily blitz the VM and start a new one if you wanted to.